Cannot fg a zsh function including less
I have this zsh function:
f() {
/usr/bin/find . -type f | less
}

When I run this function, suspend with Ctrl+z, and then run fg, it displays zsh: suspended (tty output) /usr/bin/find . -type f | and I can't resume. Why is that? How can I resume?
arch% f
zsh: suspended /usr/bin/find . -type f |
arch% fg
[2] - continued /usr/bin/find . -type f |
zsh: suspended (tty output) /usr/bin/find . -type f |
zsh: suspended (tty output) /usr/bin/find . -type f |
arch%

If I run /usr/bin/find . -type f | less directly from the command line without making it a function, it will suspend and resume normally.

This is a bug affecting zsh 5.9. It was fixed in November 2022 but there hasn't been a release made since as of December 2024.
If you do:
$ find . | less
^Z
zsh: suspended  find . | less
$ ps -Ho pid,ppid,pgid,tpgid,args
    PID    PPID    PGID   TPGID COMMAND
  11094    5260   11094   11150 /bin/zsh
  11128   11094   11128   11150   find .
  11129   11094   11128   11150   less
  11150   11094   11150   11150   ps -Ho pid,ppid,pgid,tpgid,args
$ jobs -p
[1]  + 11128 suspended  find . |
             suspended  less

11128 is indeed the PGID of the job that has find and less, and resuming works fine, but:
$ f() {find . -type f | less}
$ f
zsh: suspended  find . -type f |
$ ps -Ho pid,ppid,pgid,tpgid,args
    PID    PPID    PGID   TPGID COMMAND
  11094    5260   11094   11520 /bin/zsh
  11492   11094   11492   11520   find . -type f
  11493   11094   11492   11520   less
  11501   11094   11501   11520   /bin/zsh
  11520   11094   11520   11520   ps -Ho pid,ppid,pgid,tpgid,args
$ jobs -p
[1]  + 11493 suspended  find . -type f |
             suspended

This time, 11493 is the PID of less, not the PGID of the job that has both find and less which is 11492 instead.
So when fg tries to put the job in foreground, it does a tcsetpgrp(11493) which fails to put that job in foreground, then carries on resuming all the processes with SIGCONT, and it so happens that less upon resuming does a tcsetattr() (what the stty command typically does) which background processes are not allowed to do, so the whole process group gets a SIGTTOU signal and are suspended again.
Here, a work around would be to change the function definition to:
f() (find . | less)

That is, use a subshell rather than a command group as the function's body, so that there's only one process that the parent process needs to care about and no room for confusion.
Using:
f() {less < <(find .)}

Also seems to work (though implies an additional process for some reason).
Job control is quite tricky business especially when like zsh or ksh do, you try to run the right hand side of a pipeline in the current shell and like zsh or AT&T ksh do you try to have a more useful behaviour when hitting ^Z in a compound command (like the body of your f function here).
Note the extra 11501 process that turned up above when f was suspended. It's there so that the rest of the function can resume after the find, less are resumed (with fg or bg) and eventually terminate.
See how in bash or mksh, if you do:
f() { sleep 100; echo here; }
f

And hit ^Z, sleep is suspending but echo here is run at that point! And then if you fg, sleep is resumed, but the rest of the function has already been executed!
See the comment explaining it in the code:
/*
 * Job control in zsh
 * ==================
 *
 * A 'job' represents a pipeline; see the section JOBS in zshmisc(1)) for an
 * introduction.  The 'struct job's are allocated in the array 'jobtab' which
 * has 'jobtabsize' elements.  The job whose processes we are currently
 * preparing to execute is identified by the global variable 'thisjob'.
 *
 * A 'superjob' is a job that represents a complex shell construct that has been
 * backgrounded.  For example, if one runs '() { vi; echo }', a job is created
 * for the pipeline 'vi'.  If one then backgrounds vi (with ^Z / SIGTSTP),
 * the shell forks; the parent shell returns to the interactive prompt and
 * the child shell becomes a new job in the parent shell.  The job representing
 * the child shell to the parent shell is a superjob (STAT_SUPERJOB); the 'vi'
 * job is marked as a subjob (STAT_SUBJOB) in the parent shell.  When the child
 * shell is resumed (with fg / SIGCONT), it forwards the signal to vi and,
 * after vi exits, continues executing the remainder of the function.
 * (See workers/43565.)
 */

One of the problems (and I don't know how much if at all it participates to the problem discussed here; edit, probably not looking at the fix) is that that "superjob" is not the parent of the processes that have been suspended, so for instance can't get their exit status:
$ { (sleep 4; exit 4); echo "$?"; }
^Zzsh: suspended  ( sleep 4; exit 4; )
$ fg
[1]  + continued  ( sleep 4; exit 4; )
148
$

echo "$?" was indeed run after (sleep...) terminated and not when it was suspended like in bash, but $? reflects a suspended status, not the 4 you'd expect.
As hinted in that comment above, you can find the behaviour described in zshmisc(1) or info zsh jobs:

Note that if the job running in the foreground is a shell function, then
suspending it will have the effect of causing the shell to fork.  This
is necessary to separate the function's state from that of the parent
shell performing the job control, so that the latter can return to the
command line prompt.  As a result, even if fg is used to continue the
job the function will no longer be part of the parent shell, and any
variables set by the function will not be visible in the parent shell.
Thus the behaviour is different from the case where the function was
never suspended.  Zsh is different from many other shells in this
regard.
One additional side effect is that use of disown with a job created by
suspending shell code in this fashion is delayed: the job can only be
disowned once any process started from the parent shell has terminated.
At that point, the disowned job disappears silently from the job list.
The same behaviour is found when the shell is executing code as the
right hand side of a pipeline or any complex shell construct such as if,
for, etc., in order that the entire block of code can be managed as a
single job.  Background jobs are normally allowed to produce output, but
this can be disabled by giving the command 'stty tostop'.  If you set
this tty option, then background jobs will suspend when they try to
produce output like they do when they try to read input.
When a command is suspended and continued later with the fg or wait
builtins, zsh restores tty modes that were in effect when it was
suspended.  This (intentionally) does not apply if the command is
continued via 'kill -CONT', nor when it is continued with bg.


f() (find . | less) This little workaround is working like a charm! f() { zsh -c 'find . | less' } seems to work as well.
